# Is it possible to disallow or 'hide' methods to stop the development team using them?

Tags: c#

I work in a team of 20+ developers that includes a recent influx of newer members. Our coding standards state that the .First() extension method for IEnumerable should never be used, and instead that we should always use FirstOrDefault() and check for a null return.

I appreciate that some members may want to get into a discussion about training, enforcing coding standards or unit tests to pick up such transgressions, but in principle is it possible to cause the attempted use to throw a compile-time error?

Comment: Without care for the weird coding standards, code reviews come to mind.

Comment: Do you have any globally utilized DLLs/libraries? If so, you might be able to accomplish something similar to this via overloading the functions/methods that you want to disallow.

Comment: I didn't know the .First() extension was so evil.

Comment: @youthinkthisisntme It seems to me that you have to look at your coding standards. Always enforcing `First` over `FirstOrDefault` (or vice versa) does not make much sense - both are useful in different context.

Comment: `First` throws a *meaningful* exception. `FirstOrDefault` on the other hand, will possibly net you a `NullReferenceException` which carries a lot less meaning and can be thrown *far from the call to FirstOrDefault*. It's just a matter of a developer forgetting to test for `null`. Are you enforcing that at compile-time too?

Comment: in the context of day-to-day development Code Reviews are the answer here and i need to ensure that (a) the developers and (b) the code reviewers (same people, different roles) are aware of what to look out for. However in the context of trying to 'hide' or disallow a role, the solution provided by @Coding Gorilla is the most complete for these purposes. thanks all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best thing that you can do in terms of compile time help is:

1. Make your OWN extension method called "First" that does nothing but throw an exception.
2. Mark that method as "OBSOLETE" so that you get a compile-time warning.

I think that's the best you can do.

(some comments mentioned concern about the namespace... you would simply use the same namespace as Microsoft does [System.Linq] so that the compiler sees both).

Comment: Assuming your method is accessible in a given file, you'll get errors for ambiguous extension methods, so, there's no need for "OBSOLETE".

Comment: The problem with this idea, I would think, is that his extension method would exist in a different namespace.  Therefore wouldn't function unless the coder in question used his namespace rather than `System.Linq`.

Comment: The [ObsoleteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) can take a Boolean as second parameter. If true, there is no warning but a compilation error.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: Put the method in namespace `System.Linq`. Namespaces are open.

Comment: @RMartinhoFernandes Wouldn't that generate an error by itself, you'd have a duplicate method declaration.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: No you won't. Don't make it a duplicate method.

Comment: @RMatinhoFernandes No you're right because you would attach it to a different class.  However, in my testing here: http://pastebin.com/EWGHrLzt  The program still compiles; I would guess the compiler ignores the obsoleted method and instead uses the one from the `Enumerable` class.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: you are calling the overload of `First` that takes a predicate, but you only "forbid" the one that takes no predicate. See this: http://ideone.com/dE6qR

Comment: thanks all for the quick responses and @Coding Gorilla and RMatinhoFernandes for their specific answers

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own rule for [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) and enforce it during build.

My personal opinion is that it is waste of time. Is it really so important to forbid one particular method? There are millions of other cases where NullReferenceException can be thrown, and it is something that simply can't be found compile-time.

Comment: Even worse, using FirstOrDefault() when expecting a non-default value, will cause the error to propagate downstream, where it'll be more difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

1) Overload the functions/methods you want to disallow.
2) Add a obsolete Attribute to the overloaded function/method.
3) Set your compiler settings to not build on errors or warnings.

Doing this would allow the build to fail and any offending code to be immediately noticeable and then the offenders can be identified and trained.